# composer - symlink for local extension Typo3 v12

Tags: composer-php, typo3, symlink, typo3-extensions

I started using ddev about 3 years ago to develop my websites on typo3.
I followed this tutorial to be able to develop my exts locally:
https://t3planet.com/typo3-tutorials/install-local-typo3-extensions-composer-mode/

I noticed that since version 11 (and especially with version 12), symlinks can no longer be used to develop local extensions.

Is there an alternative way to be able to recreate the same functionality in typo3 v12 (composer 4)?

I read something on the subject in this link: but I don't understand how to configure it ...

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Extensions/Management.html

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct tutorial, yes: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Extensions/Management.html#installing-local-extensions

1. Create a folder in project root, e.g. `packages`
2. Create your extension inside a sub folder in packages
3. Add a composer.json in your extension
4. Add the `repositories` part in your root composer.json (not extension)
5. Require the extension with `composer req vendor/extension-name:@dev`

Comment: Thanks : but there's one step missing : configure Docker container "ssh" to view the folder "packages" : is there a DDEV tutorial to follow?

Comment: I don't get your problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In ddev, i think I need to create this file : "docker-compose.enviroment.yaml" inside .ddev folder, to correctly "see" the folder "local_packages" from typo3 : 

---------------------
version: '3.6'
#ddev-generated
services:
  web:
    environment:
      - TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development/DDEV
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ~/local_packages/*
        target: /var/www/html/local_packages/*

Comment: Didn't need this at all, working with ddev since years. My packages are inside the project, why do you have it in your home dir?