# Typo3 no symlinks between custom ext and public dir

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-12.x

I have no symlinks between my custom extension in `packages/` and `public/typo3conf/`.

I tried this ([composer - symlink for local extension Typo3 v12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376264/composer-symlink-for-local-extension-typo3-v12)) but without success.

Then I tried: `ln -s public/typo3conf/ packages/` and `ln -s packages/ public/typo3conf/`

This is my composer.json at root:

```
{
    "name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
    "description" : "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "type": "project",
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "typo3/class-alias-loader": true,
            "typo3/cms-composer-installers": true
        },
        "platform": {
            "php": "8.1.1"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {
        "b13/container": "^2.3",
        "colin/frontend": "^1.0",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "5.3.2",
        "typo3/cms-backend": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-core": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-dashboard": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-extbase": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-extensionmanager": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-felogin": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-filelist": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-fluid": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-form": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-frontend": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-install": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-reactions": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-seo": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-webhooks": "^12.4.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./packages/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I hope thats understandable. Let me know if you need further informations.

Comment: `ln -s packages/ public/typo3conf` is actually working for me now, but leads to "cannot access 'public/typo3conf/packages': Too many levels of symbolic links"

Comment: Since TYPO3 v12 the typo3conf/ext folder is gone for Composer-based installations. Instead, the extensions are symlinked into the vendor folder. Additionally, the type in your extension's composer.json must be set to "typo3-cms-extension" (like before). The Resources/Public folder will the be symlinked into the _assets folder in your web root folder upon installation.

Answer (score 0):

From the TYPO3 v12, there are no more symlinks between `packages/` and `public/typo3conf/`.

Your custom extension symlinks will be available in the `vendor/` directory.

Reference: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/DirectoryStructure/Index.html